# Estimated Gaussian distribution parameters are wrong

Tags: python, gaussian, log-likelihood

I'm experimenting with Gaussian distribution and its likelihood.
To figure out max likelihood I differentiate likelihood with respect to *mu* (expectation) and sigma (mean), which equal to data.mean() and data.std() correspondingly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
from scipy.stats import norm

def calculate_likelihood(x, mu, sigma): 
    n = len(x)  
    likelihood = n/2.0 * np.log(2 * np.pi) + n/2.0 * math.log(sigma **2 ) + 1/(2*sigma**2) * sum([(x_i - mu)**2 for x_i in x ])

    return likelihood

def estimate_gaussian_parameters_from_data(data):
    return data.mean(), data.std()

def main():
    mu = 0
    sigma = 2
    x_values = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 1000)
    y_values_1 = mlab.normpdf(x_values, mu, sigma)

    estimated_mu, estimated_sigma = estimate_gaussian_parameters_from_data(y_values_1)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

I expected that *estimated_mu* and *estimated_sigma* should approximately be equal to *mu* and *sigma*, but that's not the case. Instead of 0 and 2 I get 0.083 and 0.069. Do I understand anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mlab.normpdf is a pdf it returns the probability of x. Since mean is 0 you will see points around 0 having high probability. y_values_1's are the probability densities.

```
s = np.random.normal(0, 2, 1000)
```

The above code samples 1000 points which are normally distributed with mean 0 and std 2

```
np.mean(s) == 0.018308805079364696 and np.std(s) == 1.9467605916031896
```

Comment: You're hitting the nail's head, but please do not call values of `y` probabilities. They are probability densities.